# Closure error with loops in javascript

Tags: javascript

I had a bug, it went like this

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var v = arr[i]
    var obj=new Thing
    obj.TheCallback = function(e) { blah = v; domorestuff(); ... }
    obj.runCodeToExecuteTheCallback()
}
```

The problem is `v` inside the function is using the `v` from the last loop. It's a closure thing where you can access variables in your parent scope. But my question is...

Why is javascript reusing `v` in each iteration? When it goes out of scope (at the end of the loop) i dont except it to be MODIFIED from any other scope unless it was passed in (such as the inner function). Why the heck is javascript clobbering my variable? Is there some kind of reason for this design? Is it a bug that has been decided never to be fixed?

Comment: You're redefining v to be the v'th item of an array inside the loop? Could you maybe post a working example instead of this piece of pseudo code?

Comment: @GolezTrol: tiny mistake. It should be obvious i meant `i` as i is for loop and v is for value

Comment: Yeah, not only that, be this whole code won't work. It would be easier for those who invest time to help you, if they could reproduce the problem and work to a solution from there.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I already know the solution to the bug. I just don't know why the bug exist hence the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a *very* common issue people encounter.

JavaScript doesn't have block scope, just function scope. So each function you create in the loop is created in the *same* variable scope, so they're referencing the *same* `v` variable.

To create a new scope, you need to invoke a function, and pass in whatever you want to exist in a new scope.

```
function createCallback( x ) {
    return function(e) { blah = x; domorestuff(); ... }
}

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var v = arr[v]
    var obj=new Thing
    obj.TheCallback = createCallback( v );
    obj.runCodeToExecuteTheCallback()
}
```

Here I invoked the `createCallback()` function, pass in `v`, and had `createCallback()` *return* a function that references the local variable *(named `x` in the function, though you could name it `v` as well).*

The returned function is of course assigned to `obj.TheCallback`.

Its variable scope exists as long as the function exists, so it will continue to have reference to any variables that it needs that were in the variable scope when it was created.

Comment: so codeblocks/loops dont have their own scope!?! still... wtf. How does variables in loops not clobber variables outside of the loop!?! unless it does and i am lucky i never ran into that problem?

Comment: @acidzombie24: Well, they do clobber, because they're all in the same variable scope. You just need to be sure to not reuse a variable name in a block thinking that it is any different from the rest of the variables in the local scope. ...I'd note that Firefox *does* have block scope via the `let` expression, and the same syntax is likely coming to the ECMAScript standard. Until then, a block is nothing special with respect to variable scope.

Comment: @patrick: wow wtf and thanks. I'm really glad i never ran into that yet!

Comment: Might want to check out some JavaScript tutorials/etc. then; things like scoping rules are an important thing to know--there might be other gotchas you haven't run across yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var i, obj;

for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    obj = new Thing;

    (function ( v ) {
        obj.callback = function ( e ) {
            // do stuff with v
        };
    })( arr[i] );

}
```

Comment: I know the solution. I am asking why the bug exist

Comment: @acid Patrick explained what this is about. It's not a bug, but it's just the way scope works in JavaScript.