# Why isn't setTimeout working in this function?

Tags: javascript, tabs, toggle, settimeout, addeventlistener

I've created a function that generates tabs. It works by taking element IDs as parameters, and then generates an event listener, which then responds to click events of any of the elements. It's a little complicated, so I'll just post it:

```
function toggleTabs() {
  var panel = [], li = [];
  for(var i = 1, j = arguments.length; i <= j; i++) {
    li[i] = document.getElementById(arguments[i - 1]);
    panel[i] = 'panel' + i;
  }  
  document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    var target = event.target.id;
    for(var i = 1, j = li.length; i <= j; i++) {
      if(li[i].id === target) {
        document.getElementById(panel[i]).style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById(panel[i]).style.opacity = '1';
          window.alert('fired');
        }, 500);
        li[i].className = 'active';
      } else if(target.substring(0,3) === 'tab'){
        document.getElementById(panel[i]).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(panel[i]).style.opacity = '0';
        li[i].className = null;
      }
    }
  }, false);
}
if(url === '/customers') { toggleTabs('tab-c-featured', 'tab-c-view'); }
```

As it is, it works, but I want the elements to fade in when it is triggered, which isn't happening despite a transition effecting existing on the elements. I thought this might be because of the display property changing also, overriding the fade-in opacity effect, so I decided to add a timeout effect - but it isn't working. I added a window alert to test it, and for some reason it wont fire, why is this?

thanks

Comment: Have you checked the console in your browser to see if your code throws an error? If the line before your alert fails, that could explain why you dont see the alert.

Answer (score 1):

There is possible error. It's necessary to use closures when you create a deferred function calls inside of a cycle.
So here is the mistake `document.getElementById(panel[i]).style.opacity = '1';`

When the function will be called, `panel[i]` will refers to the last element of the `panels` list. 
To avoid this behaviour wrap your calls to closure, e.g. 
`setTimeout(function (thePanel) {
    return function(){
        // do whatever you need with thePanel
    }
}(panel[i]), 500);`

[There is more info about this problem at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409099/1838263)

Comment: Thanks,

I think this gets me on the right track. If nothing else, you've encouraged me to learn more about closures in JS.